# Permissions to set job Enable/Disable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job

The database user has been granted `SQLAgentOperatorRole`, but there are still error when set job enable/disable. The error message is:

> SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysjobs', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'

We set the job enable/disable by `sp_update_job`.

Comments:

When executing the following statement, will get the error.

```
bool result = ObjectInstance.ExecuteStoreQuery<bool>("EXEC usp_prod_SetJobStatus @jobName={0}, @isEnable={1}", jobName, isEnable).FirstOrDefault();
```

But, while use the following statement, it will execute successful.

```
 ObjectInstance.ExecuteStoreCommand("EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name={0}, @enabled={1}", jobName, isEnable);
```

usp_prod_SetJobStatus SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_prod_SetJobStatus]
    @jobName VARCHAR(200),
    @isEnable BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @jobId uniqueidentifier
    DECLARE @result BIT

    SELECT @jobId = job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name = @jobName
    IF(@jobId IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        EXEC @result = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name=@jobName, @enabled=@isEnable    
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @result = 1
    END

    SELECT  @result
END
```

Comment: What is the exact command you're using? The documentation says that SQLAgentOperatorRole can only specify two parameters and if there are extra parameters then the procedure will fail. That may or may not be your problem, but without seeing what command you're executing no one can really help.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please review for detail. The scenario are: 1. User1 has SQLAgentOperatorRole permissions, and execute the above two calling methods, the first one was failed, while the other one was successed. 2. User2 has sysadmin role, the two methods has been executed successfully. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem. The reason is that there is no SELECT permission on sysjobs table for the user. So, we need to grant the SELECT perssion for the user.

```
USE msdb
GRANT SELECT ON msdb.dbo.sysjobs TO useName
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given agent operator role its having enable and disable but SQLAgentOperatorRole members can enable or disable local jobs they do not own by using the stored procedure sp_update_job and specifying values for the @enabled and the @job_id (or @job_name) parameters. If a member of this role specifies any other parameters for this stored procedure, execution of the procedure will fail ..You have to execute permissions on sql server agnet .

Comment: I have edited the question, please review for detail. And the user also have the SQLAgentOperatorRole permissions. I have tested two calling methods as above, but the first one is failed while the second one is successed. Thanks for your comments.